CloudSQL WAL Storage Stuck in SWITCHING_TO_CLOUD_STORAGE State
I recently moved the Write-Ahead Log (WAL) storage for my PostgreSQL Cloud SQL instance from Disk to Cloud Storage using the following command:
gcloud sql instances patch <INSTANCE_NAME> \
      --switch-transaction-logs-to-cloud-storage

It’s been 4-5 days, and the WAL storage state still shows SWITCHING_TO_CLOUD_STORAGE when I run:
gcloud sql instances list --show-transactional-log-storage-state


I referred to the Google Cloud documentation, but it doesn’t mention any specific timeframe for completing the switch.
My Questions:

How long does it typically take to fully switch WAL storage to Cloud Storage?
Is there any way to troubleshoot or expedite the process?

Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated!

The overall process of switching the storage location takes approximately the duration of the transaction log retention period (days) to complete. As soon as you start the switch, transaction logs start accruing in Cloud Storage. During the operation, you can check the status of the overall process by using the command in Check the storage location of transaction logs used for PITR.

Please refer to the Documentation to know how to set transaction log retention. Also check if the size of your write-ahead logs(WAL) are causing an issue for your instance you can refer to the Documentation on how to overcome this.
